# Get table name of class at runtime in ServiceStack.OrmLite / avoid hardcoding table names

Tags: c#, .net, orm, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I use [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) and want to get the total count of rows from a table. I currently do as pointed out in the [ServiceStack.OrmLite documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) via

```
db.Scalar<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User");
```

However, the table's name `User` might change in the future so I am looking for a way not to hardcode it. Is it possible to get the table's name from its according class, like i.e.

```
string table_name = db.GetTableName<User> ();
db.Scalar<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", table_name);
```

?

Comment: I don't know how to dynamically get the table name, but in your particular case, you don't have to manually write SQL for a count(*) operation. You could do something like **dbConnection.GetScalar<YourObject, long>(e => Sql.Count(e.Id));**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 2 ways to access the config metadata of your types is with:

```
ModelDefinition<User>.Definition.ModelName;
typeof(User).GetModelMetadata().ModelName;
```

Although in some databases you need to quote your table name, you can do this with:

```
var modelDef = ModelDefinition<User>.Definition;
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetQuotedTableName(modelDef)
```

So yeah you can wrap this in an extension method that does what you want with:

```
public static MyOrmLiteExtensions {
    public static string GetTableName<T>(this IDbConnection db) {
        var modelDef = ModelDefinition<T>.Definition;
        return OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetQuotedTableName(modelDef);
    }
}
```

Comment: This extension method is now part of ServiceStack but it's called `GetQuotedTableName`, if you want the name of the table that can be safely used in custom queries

Comment: Is there an equivalent method for getting column names?

Comment: @Guerrilla Checkout `IDbConnection.GetTableColumns()`

Comment: @mythz How do you relate the property name on class to the column name returned?

Comment: @Guerrilla The `ModelDefinition` in my answer has `FieldDefinitions` with the columns/properties relevant to OrmLite.

Comment: That has the name of the properties but what has the name of the property and the name of the column so i can go from name of property to name of column?

Comment: I added ModelDefinition<T>.Definition to watch window and searched 10 levels deep for the postgresql column name and it didn't find it.  My purpose is making a custom query without have to manually enter the column names as strings that can break

Comment: @Guerrilla Don’t know what 10 level deep you’re referring to but the entire source code of OrmLite is available at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite. Note OrmLite is a code-first ORM, it doesn’t tell you what the column name is, you tell it. OrmLite assumes the column name is the same as the property name (using configured naming convention), when the column name is different, you have to specify as such using the [Alias] attribute, both Name & Alias is on FieldDefinition. In future please ask new questions in a new clearly defined question i.e. instead of hijacking comments